# Highcharts.js draws ugly series line

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

Please look at this example

http://jsfiddle.net/LT5Xb/

I used following config to change y axis range

```
yAxis: {
    tickPositions: [-3, 0, 3],
    gridLineWidth: 0
},
```

Green series line (trust) is thinner than the rest of the chart where `x >= 3` and `x <= 4`.

Can I make it look the same? I really want y axis to be between -3 and 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line is being sliced in half since it appears on the edge of the drawing "canvas".

Try these yAxis options:

```
       yAxis: {
            tickPositions: [-3, 0, 3],
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            max: 3.1,
            endOnTick: false
        },
```

Update [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LT5Xb/4/).

For Lower end, just set a min with the max value-->

```
yAxis: {
      tickPositions: [-3, 0, 3],
      gridLineWidth: 0,
      max: 3.1,
      min: -3.1, // I added this!
      endOnTick: false,
      startOnTick: false // and this!
},
```

Yet another [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LT5Xb/6/).

Comment: Yes that solves this issue on the upper limit. Unfortunately when you have [-3,-3] data it's still broken and setting min value doesn't help. It's rendered correctly when you change tickPositions to [-3.1, 0, 3] but that's not really good solution because you get misleading label insted

Comment: For the lower limit, invert what I've done above.  See updated answer.  The key is the `start/endOnTick` and `min/max` values.  It allows your ticks to be independent of the range.

Comment: I didn't set startOnTick that's why it didn't work previously. Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly bug, reported to our developers here: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2099

Thank you for suggestion.

Comment: Also I noticed that line disappears and it's covered by bottom scale http://jsfiddle.net/LT5Xb/1/